# CDI deployment failure on Payara 4.1.2.172 Server

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cdi, payara

I am trying to deploy a small project on a Payara 4.1.2.172 server while working through a Java EE book, but I get the following error:

```
Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:Service class org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEBeanRegistrant didn't implement the required interface
```

I am using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate as an IDE. I tried using different CDI implementations like Weld 2.0.3 / 1.1.8 / 1.0.1 and even Apache Open Webbeans 1.1.4 but the error stays the same.

The search for this error gave me no results. Hopefully someone can point me into the right direction so I can fix this error.

Update: I am getting the same error in Eclipse.

Here is the stack trace:

```
    Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:Service class org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEBeanRegistrant didn't implement the required interface
java.lang.RuntimeException: Service class org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEBeanRegistrant didn't implement the required interface
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadClass(ServiceLoader.java:230)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadService(ServiceLoader.java:210)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.loadServiceFile(ServiceLoader.java:182)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.reload(ServiceLoader.java:162)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader.iterator(ServiceLoader.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.weld.DeploymentImpl.getExtensions(DeploymentImpl.java:474)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:329)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The class in the message has **se** in it, which makes me think it is trying to bootstrap Weld for Java SE, not EE. Is this what you want? Payara should have a CDI implementation built-in, you should not need to provide your own. Check your build, is it including Weld jars in the deployed application? (E.g. they should have `scope: provided` in Maven.)

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Thank you for your answer Nikos. I am getting the same error when using the CDI implementation that comes with Payara. It's even the same when I choose to use Apache open Webbeans. I don't know if something is perhaps cached in a wrong way. Also, I updated my post with a stacktrace. Maybe you can take a look.

Comment: Check the libraries of the deployed artifact (war? ear?) to see whether Weld jars are included. They should not. Tomcat does not include a CDI implementation by default (if I am not mistaken). So if the instructions on the book are for Tomcat, this could be the reason. I cannot extract any other useful information from the stack trace.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I found some weld files in my glassfish/modules folder which didn't belong there. After removal Payara is working fine again. Perhaps you want to create an answer so I can select it as best answer.